# Trouble Accessing Shopify Products using shopify-api-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm attempting to access products in my private Shopify app using the shopify-api-node module but I'm getting a 403 error.

Here's the code I've written with the help of another Stackoverflow post:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const Shopify = require('shopify-api-node');
const https = require('https');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const {request, gql, GraphQLClient} = require('graphql-request');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;



const apikey = "*";
const apipassword = "*";
const endpoint = "https://<store>.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07/graphql.json"


const shopify = new Shopify({
    shopName: '<store>.myshopify.com',
    apiKey: '*',
    password: '*',
    autoLimit: true
});

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render(path.join(__dirname, '/views/index.ejs'));
    shopify.product.count()
    .then(async (count) => {
        if (count > 0) {

            const pages = Math.ceil(count / 250);
            let products = [];

            for (i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
                // use Promise.all instead of waiting for each response
                const result = await shopify.product.list({
                    limit: 250,
                    page: i + 1,
                    fields: 'id, variants'
                });
                products = products.concat(result);
            }
            // products array should have all the products. Includes id and variants
            console.log(products);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
})

app.get('/treasures', function(req, res) {
    res.render(path.join(__dirname, '/views/treasure.ejs'));
});

app.get('/poetry_books', (req, res) => {

    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(port);
```

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better approach that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the page parameter anymore. Try something like that instead:

```
let last_id = 0;
do {
    const results = await ShopifyAPI.product.list({
      limit: 250,
      since_id: last_id,
    });

    // Do something with your product data

    last_id = (results.length === 250 ? results[results.length - 1].id : 0);
} while (last_id);
```